# AEM Scheduled Page/Asset Activation Programatically or through Workflow

Tags: java, workflow, aem

Need to Acivate an asset at a Scheduled time provided by User Programatically using SCHEDULED PAGE/ASSET ACTIVATION workflow. I need to set the timeoutHandler value when I call this Workflow from my java code. I'm not sure how to do that. Once this property is set for my workflow instance, I'm hoping AEM should take care of the activation at Scheduled time.

[image]

Comment: Why the OOB on/off time properties do not work for you?